Dismissed after completing dissertation and one committee review
I was dismissed from a university after completing my study and had undergone one full committee review. The reason for dismissal was being over the university-imposed time limits. I was only a few weeks away, just needed one more committee review, an AQR review, and the defense. I always complied with my committee directives.
I was impacted by a natural disaster (when Texas froze in February 2021). My house was destroyed by bursting pipes, 6 weeks without water, no power or heat for days, etc. I provided my proof to the university, but they replied they were "under no obligation to consider this event."
I'm now unemployed and broke. After years of study, how do I proceed and receive what I paid for and earned in time & research?  Cannot afford a lawyer.
Just a PS after reading other questions posted on this forum it appears that the responses left here, for me were exceptionally harsh and unified in a rather odd fashion- again in comparison to other similar posts left. Further, my post was edited on one occasion, but not by my hand.  This sort of ability provided by this forum,  to tamper with the post of another is rather dangerous, and a bit telling in a negative way. Thank you.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Okay, so I think I can deduce what school this program was through.
I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but it looks like this purely-online PhD program may have largely been a scam, preying on not-so-informed student hopefuls.
The university that I'm thinking of is a private, for-profit Christian university in the western U.S called Grand Canyon University. Last year, the U.S. government imposed several major sanctions for failures of its PhD program, per Wikipedia:

In 2023 the Department of Education fined the company $37.7 million
for deceiving students about the cost of doctoral degrees. The
department alleged that 78% of students graduating in those programs
paid about 25% more than the cost that GCU represented, with much of
the extra charges accumulating from additional "continuation classes"
for completing the dissertation requirement. Only 2% paid the
represented cost. The school disputed the allegation, claiming in
addition that it provides more information than is legally required.
GCU is the largest recipient of federal student aid. In addition to
the fine, the department imposed conditions on the school to continue
participating in the federal student aid programs.
Also in 2023, the Federal Trade Commission filed a federal lawsuit
alleging that GCU deceived prospective doctoral students about the
cost of its program and its for-profit status. The suit asserted that
GCU paid 60% of its revenues to the for-profit Grand Canyon Education
company and was the company's most significant source of revenue. The
university and company had the same CEO.

If I'm correct, then the dismissal may be some continuing form of shakedown for further tuition fees, and/or you may be nowhere near an actual successful PhD completion. Even if this is not the same institution, it could be a similar fraud with a different name.
It seems like the OP may need to, most sadly, just walk away from this scam and chalk it up to a painful lesson learned. OP has said, "Cannot afford a lawyer", so legal remedy seems out unless they can get an attorney on a contingency basis. Or file a complaint with the U.S. Department of Education (see above), or maybe the state attorney general. More-knowledgeable people here may have other ideas. I'm very sorry if this is the case.

Knowing now that this is an online PhD, which frankly I forgot even existed before your comment, I think you've got it totally right. OP's post is confusing because it's not describing a normal PhD program because OP was never in a normal PhD program.

A complaint to the US DOE or the state attorney generals office wouldn't hurt, if this is the case.

In response to comments about the identity of the institution alluded to, and considering that the quotes included actually do contain the name of the institution if you look carefully, I just went ahead and named them directly. We do have a policy against accusations against individuals and institutions, but I would say that reference to an institution fined by the government for misconduct is exempt as "widely reported or discussed".

@ScottSeidman: Good idea, I added that.

Bryan Krause
Thank you.  And again let it be noted that I never mentioned the name of an institution here.  Also, no one asked here if I had IRB approval and was officially moved to PHD candidacy, which I was.  I defended my proposal and was awarded PhD candidacy, and completed the study in full.  I had undergone, completed, finished one full committee review of the submitted manuscript.

@KaePeach No one said you did. Similarly, you do not need to keep copying the "reason you were dismissed" into comments talking about entirely different things. Please read this answer carefully; if it does in fact describe your institution, we don't need to know, but if that's the case then you should know that the degree you were pursuing likely has no value, your money was stolen by that institution, and further attempts to obtain your degree are likely to result in more money being stolen from you.

@KaePeach Neither did you mention you're working with human subjects, so no one knew to ask if you had IRB approval. Even if you had mentioned, I wouldn't have thought to ask anyway.

"ScottSeidman: Good idea, I added that. –
Daniel R. Collins"
Thank you "RE: A complaint to the US DOE or the state attorney generals office wouldn't hurt, if this is the case".   Cheers!

Bryan Krause
Thank you. I do believe there will emerge a positive outcome , especially as there is a full study out there that is mine, and does hold value as it stands shoulder to shoulder with similar research within that domain, and it extended that research, so yes, it does indeed have value, in addition to the dollar amount I paid, and the time and integrity placed into that body of research- lots were put in, etc.  Happy Labor Day Weekend Bryan Krause

Azor Ahai -him Thank you , no worries.  Thank you for your time & input, it's appreciated. ( and ultimately my problem, right, sigh!)  Happy Labor Day weekend.  Cheers!

@KaePeach Victims of other types of scam think that the person they're communicating with in another country has real romantic interest in them and they just need to send that additional $10,000 so they can get out of the bad situation they are in, or that they're about to come into a lot of money having helped a Nigerian prince access their funds that are held up in banking regulation. Be wary.

Bryan Krause
Thank you.  This is indeed a legitimate place, as I was there in person for a residency.  But I get what you're saying and hear about these sorts of things daily just on our neighborhood forums. Buyer beware, the thing is though, in regards to my case,  when I was accepted, there were no identifiable issues with the institution.  Rather it was on par and parallel with it's fellow programs, institutions etc.  Similarly, enjoy your Labor Day holiday weekend.  Your input too is appreciated! Cheers!

Your description is rather brief, and obviously from your own perspective, and reflects obviously those things you have visibility of.  For example, when asked if your advisor supported you, you say "...my advisor told me that they did support me, but the decision made to dismiss me was not theirs."  Well, behind closed doors, that conversation could have gone many ways, and still be accurately described by your advisor.  It could range all the way from "I would prefer if we did not remove this student from the program" to "This is the best student I've ever had, and if we allow this student to continue, please be assured that this student will be completely finished within the next 45 days".  Those are both "support", but at very different levels, and will have different impacts upon decision makers.  You really have no way to know which is closest to your situation, so obviously, we don't either.
There are things that we can surmise.  Presumably, your program accepted you, and has put many financial and time resources into supporting you during your tenure there.  Because of this, if your program is anything like other US programs that I've seen, there would have been people thinking long and hard about whether your case called for dismissal or not, and dismissal is a final option.  In my experience, dismissal of a PhD student usually occurs when people don't believe that the degree can be salvaged.
Because you can only tell us your side, we have to fill in the other side on our own, based on what our experience is.  This brings me to one of two possible scenarios.  The first is exactly as you state it.  You hit some deadline that was carved in stone, and the program had no choice other than separating you, and the reason you were given is perfectly accurate, and that the same outcome would happen to every other student that timed out.  The second is that your situation is not entirely what you understand it to be, your degree award wasn't as sure of a thing as you indicate, and the deadline thing, although probably a real thing, isn't the only reason why you were separated, and the real question is "why didn't they make an exception to this deadline rule for me?"
All the commenters and answerers have their own feelings about which situation your own situation is closest to, and none of them, including myself could know for certain.  Fortunately, it makes little difference to what your approach would be.
If your school has an ombudsperson, then you should make an appointment with the ombudsperson to discuss your case and see if they can see a way for you to appeal the situation.  If your school doesn't have an ombudsman program, then you need to find another person in another role to help you figure it out.  I suggest that person is probably the Dean of Graduate Studies.
The ombudsperson option is a bit likelier to help you find satisfaction, just because of the different roles Deans and ombudspeople have.
When you have these discussions, I think a valid approach would be to let them know that you feel blindsided.  When a student is in danger of being removed from a graduate program, I think it's fair to say that the student should be told that they are in such danger in time for them to remediate and prevent that bad outcome.  You apparently have not been afforded that courtesy, and that doesn't feel right.
You might offer to waive any financial support if they allow you to finish your degree.  Yes, money is often a driver of decisions like the one you've been on the receiving end of, so taking that off the table for the school might help.  I know you said you're broke, and I'm sorry about that, but if you're really a few short steps away from finishing, it may not be too unbearable for too long.
I suspect what you'll find when you start talking to these people is that there are those in your program that don't believe you're as close to finishing as you think you are, and even some who doubt your ability to finish your degree at all.  I suspect this because it tracks better with my experiences with such situations, but I have no way of knowing, obviously.  In any case, you've posted for help and advice, and pointing this out isn't an attempt to be "harsh", but an effort to let you know about how the people you might be working with to challenge the outcome might be thinking about your case.
To revisit the high point, your most powerful argument is probably that you received inadequate feedback about your status along the way.  That means that even if the decision to remove you was the "right" decision, there were fairer ways to make it that would have afforded you the opportunity to address a bad situation in time to fix it.  Couple this with an offer on your part to forego all or some of your financial support, and you can argue that a situation where both your and your program win something and lose something is a fair and equitable outcome for this situation.

Scott Seidman Thank you for your very thoughtful response.  I will review this at  full lenght. Per "The ombudsperson option is a bit likelier to help you find satisfaction, just because of the different roles Deans and ombudspeople have."  Your suggestion is fitting. This institution does not have an ombuds.

As part of their operating practices, US universities (especially state-funded) should typically have established policies on how they handle petitions to extend deadlines on the basis of extenuating circumstances, especially when the petitions are submitted in advance of the deadline. After-the-fact petitions may be documented to end with cold dismissal, as you've experienced. So, first off ...
--> Update yourself on the procedures to petition for an extension of deadline and assure that you followed them exactly, especially before the deadline not after.
As part of graduate school policies, you were likely also required to register for dissertation credits or equivalent official coursework to certify being engaged in your dissertation research during your program of study. Such registration comes with a presumption that you will complete the stated work for the credit hours awarded. Petitions for an overall excuse due to extenuating circumstances may take into consideration the extent that you noted the absence on official records at the time the incident occurred. By example, the university may expect that you should have filed for an academic withdrawal of some kind from your course work obligations for the dissertation research in the semester of concern. So, next off ...
--> Assemble the documentation that indicates that your petition now for extenuating circumstances was also properly recorded by all duly expected actions at the time of the incident.
Your dissertation advisor must have been engaged in your initial petition. So, next off ...
--> Re-engage your dissertation advisor to help you sort through the next best options, as noted next.
Finally, the university must have documentations on the processes needed and supporting officers in place that should help you start an appeal. The presumptions for successful appeal should be a) you filed your petition for an extension in advance (not after) the deadline, b) your dissertation advisor was and remains fully engaged and fully supportive of your petition as well as the appeal, and c) you followed all procedures for the initial petition as per the university's documentation to the letter. Absent that you meet these criteria, an internal appeal, as well as an inference that you must hire a lawyer, could otherwise be futile. Or, bluntly said, when this fall-out was due to a failure on the part of your advisor and you to act properly and in advance, you may be left with no steps back.
